# unwind: Unknown symbol address

Tags: android, linux

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Debugging linux kernel panic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12523505/debugging-linux-kernel-panic)

I am debugging a one time issue. Where device crashed whil browsing gmail in android phone. Public Wifi is used to connected net. 
So far I found that a page fault occured in vector_swi, that lr value found (to get SWI instruction) is wrong. The process running at that time was UEventObserver.

### Here is the process information.

```
Task name: UEventObserver, pid: 675, cpu: 1, 
state: 0x0, exit_state: 0x0, stack_base: 0xd6eae000
Stack: 
[<C078939C>] __schedule+0x5b0
[<FFFFFFFF>] (null)+0x0
[<1>] (null)+0x1
```

unwind: Unknown symbol address 00000001
unwind: Index not found 00000001

---

Here is the kernel log for crash.

```
<1>[37655.473976] Unable to handle kernel paging request at virtual address 40025694

<1>[37655.473976] pgd = d7138000

<1>[37655.474007] [40025694] *pgd=9ec1a831, *pte=bf2e659d, *ppte=00000000

<0>[37655.474038] Internal error: Oops: 17 [#1] PREEMPT SMP

<4>[37655.474038] Modules linked in:

<4>[37655.474068] CPU: 1    Not tainted  (3.0.21-g572d9be-00004-g4ec4db2 #1)

<4>[37655.474099] PC is at vector_swi+0x28/0x88

<4>[37655.474129] LR is at 0x40025698

<4>[37655.474160] pc : c01065a8    lr : 40025698    psr : 60000093

<4>[37655.474160] sp : d6eaffb0  ip : 4062c18c  fp : 5ed97c24

<4>[37655.474190] r10: 58702b64  r9 : 5ea56f98  r8 : 20000010

<4>[37655.474221] r7 : 000000a8  r6 : 41b13530  r5 : 4062c270  r4 : 4062c140

<4>[37655.474251] r3 : 00000000  r2 : ffffffff  r1 : 00000001  r0 : 5ed97bd0

<4>[37655.474251] Flags: nZCv  IRQs off  FIQs on  Mode SVC_32  ISA ARM  Segment user

<4>[37655.474282] Control: 10c5787d  Table: 9ec3806a  DAC: 00000015

<4>[37655.474282]
```

Comment: Yes, It is same log but diffrent user, I wanted to know more about unwind: Unknown symbol address that why it is happened. Any suggestion tht why it is happened?

Comment: The stack is corrupt or it has ended. During unwinding, the backtrace function tries to find the symbolic name for all function addresses, but it fails to find a symbol address for `0x1` since there's no code there.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Ramp dump shows exception (Vector_swi) occured when process UEventObserver is running and lr value is wrong. Any comment that what has gone wrong?

Comment: when switched to vecor_swi, pc value of process I.e. next instruction of SVC/SWI (in this context) should load. But lr value is invalid how it can happen?

Comment: That's what I was confused about at the other answer. The `swi` source instruction should *never* be invalid unless something is wrong in the kernel, vector table or page table. And none of those is likely unless you've made kernel modifications.

Comment: We did not made any change in kernel on these code. So far we got this issue only one time. If something wrong with kernel, vector table or page table, then it should reproduce always. Stack address of UEventObserver is 0xD6EAE000 and sp value in vector_swi shows D6EAFFB0.

Comment: I'm tempted to say it's a fluke...I wouldn't worry about it too much unless the customer complains loudly or the problem recurs. You and @shunty at the same company or something?